# VBA nested IF in excel

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement

I am relatively new to VBA. I am trying to write a code for nested IFs in VBA. I have the following code, yet the output is wrong. How can I make the nested if function work?

```
    Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()


  If Range("H2") = 1 Then
     Range("X3") = "$CT$10:$CT$150"

       If Range("H2") = 2 Then
     Range("X3") = "$CZ$10:$CZ$150"

      If Range("H2") = 3 Then
     Range("X3") = "$DF$10:$DF$150"

     If Range("H2") = 4 Then
     Range("X3") = "$DL$10:$DL$150"

     If Range("H2") = 5 Then
     Range("X3") = "$DR$10:$DR$150"

     If Range("H2") = 6 Then
     Range("X3") = "$DX$10:$DX$150"

     If Range("H2") = 7 Then
     Range("X3") = "$ED$10:$ED$150"

     If Range("H2") = 8 Then
     Range("X3") = "$EJ$10:$EJ$150"

     If Range("H2") = 9 Then
     Range("X3") = "$EP$10:$EP$150"

     If Range("H2") = 10 Then
     Range("X3") = "$EV$10:$EV$150"

     If Range("H2") = 11 Then
     Range("X3") = "$FB$10:$FH$150"

     If Range("H2") = 12 Then
     Range("X3") = "$FH$10:$FH$150"



  End If
  End If
  End If
  End If
  End If
  End If
  End If
  End If
  End If
  End If
  End If
  End If



End Sub
```

The code somehow works only if H2 = 1. Otherwise it does not work.

Comment: Use `Select Case`.  The problem is you are nesting the Ifs so it only will test the others if H2 =1  if H2<>1 it will not even test the others as they are inside the first if.

Comment: Except the first `IF`, replace all other IFs with `ELSEIF` and in the end just keep one `EndIF`. Delete the rest of the `End Ifs`

Comment: IF isn't a function its a keyword, the return from Range is not an integer, set breakpoints on the areas where you want to check then use the debugger to examine the Ranges.

Answer (score 10):

Take a step back - you have a set distance between each column, depending on `H2` value.

You don't need `IF` or `Select Case`, just some quick arithmetic:

```
Sub t()
Dim startCol As Long, tmpCol As Long

startCol = 98 ' This is the `CT` Column

With Worksheets("Sheet1") ' Change as needed
    tmpCol = startCol + 6 * (.Range("H2").Value - 1)

    Dim rng As Range
    Set rng = .Range(.Cells(10, tmpCol), .Cells(150, tmpCol))
    .Range("X3").Value = rng.Address
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Gosh darn you and your patterns. :)

Comment: @ScottCraner - As much as I love lengthy `Select Case`/`If` statements, you gotta love a good pattern [when it works](https://imgs.xkcd.com/comics/computer_problems.png)!

Comment: I think that this is the best solution. +1

Answer (score 4):

The syntax for the IF-THEN-ELSE statement in Microsoft Excel is:

```
If condition_1 Then
   result_1

ElseIf condition_2 Then
  result_2

...

ElseIf condition_n Then
   result_n

Else
   result_else

End If
```

Comment: To clarify, the solution does not constitute as a nested statement. "Nested" if statements are not needed for this case.

Answer (score 4):

For something like this I like to use Select Case:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    With Worksheets("Sheet1") ' change to your sheet
        Select Case .Range("H2")
            Case 1
                .Range("X3") = "$CT$10:$CT$150"
            Case 2
                .Range("X3") = "$CZ$10:$CZ$150"

            '... The rest

            Case Else
                .Range("X3") = ""
        End Select
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3):

You are nesting the if statements so to work down the code they all need to be true which is impossible. You should format it like this:

```
If Range("H2") = 1 Then
    Range("X3") = "$CT$10:$CT$150"
ElseIf Range("H2") = 2 Then
    Range("X3") = "$CZ$10:$CZ$150"
ElseIf Range("H2") = 3 Then
    Range("X3") = "$DF$10:$DF$150"

...

End If
```

However in your situation I would advice using a `select case` to make the code look cleaner and easier to read.

Answer (score 3):

Your cases are consecutive integers. Just put it in an array:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim addresses As Variant

    addresses = Array("$CT$10:$CT$150", "$CZ$10:$CZ$150", "$DF$10:$DF$150", "$DL$10:$DL$150", _
                    "$DR$10:$DR$150", "$DX$10:$DX$150", "$ED$10:$ED$150", "$ED$10:$ED$150", _
                    "$EJ$10:$EJ$150", "$EP$10:$EP$150", "$EV$10:$EV$150", "$FB$10:$FH$150", "$FH$10:$FH$150")

    Range("X3").Value = addresses(Range("H2").Value - 1)

End Sub
```